# R: Speeding up nested apply calls

Tags: r, apply

I am attempting to code up a piece of logic that seems to require nested `*apply` calls.

```
mProb = matrix(rbeta(1000*5, shape1 = 2, shape2 = 3), nrow = 1000, ncol = 5)
vSize = c(900, 1100, 1300, 450, 620)

mIndices = apply(mProb, 1, function(x) {
  do.call(rbind, lapply(1:5, function(y) {
    cbind(sample.int(n = vSize[y], size = floor(vSize[y]*x[y])), y) 
  })) 
})
```

Is there a more elegant way to code this? I can provide context to the code if required.

Answer (score 0):

I think `mapply()` is quite a bit more elegant and clean for this problem, and it seems a bit faster:

```
mIndices <- mapply(sample.int, size=floor(t(mProb) * vSize), n=vSize    )
dim(mIndices) <- c(5,1000)
```

mIndices is now a two-dimensional list, with the first dimension corresponding to the 
elements of vSize, and the second dim corresponding to replicate number. If you *really*
want it in the list-of-matrices, you could then use a nested apply to reshape it:

```
mIndices <- lapply(1:1000, function(s) {
    do.call(rbind, mapply(cbind, mIndices[,s], 1:5)  )
})
```